# Objc Runtime selection of import class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, runtime, conditional-compilation

Im just wondering if there is a way to select what classes to import at runtime. I can see that I can use runtime attributes like #ifdef's to select the class but my issue is how can I choose which class to load depending on a global variable in my project?

i.e:

```
#if ([SystemProperties sharedSystemProperties].clientVersion isEqualToString:@"1.0"])
     #import "Entities_1.0.h"
#else
     #import "Entities.h"
#endif
```

Is there a way to run code in the ifdef statement, or am I going about it the wrong way? Can I define global variable that I can change at runtime that I can access from the ifdef?

Thanks

Comment: Side note, the client version is set depending on what server version it is hooking up to. i.e. If the user has not updated their server than they should be the old version files. This can only be set at runtime.

Comment: `#ifdef` isn't a runtime feature; it happens even before compilation. Are you saying you have two completely different implementations of this class and want to pick between them?

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for your response. Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Raven: Do the two classes have the same public interface (methods, properties), so that only the implementation is different?